# Why a gap between ul li

Tags: html, css

In the following code, I am not able to understand that why is there a small margin between the green li's Home , Products , Services , About Us, Contact

I have set the margin and padding to 0px in both `.ul` and `.li` properties. Then why is there a gap between the green li's?

```css
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}


html,body {
 margin: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(173,192,241,1);
    }

.wrapper {
 height: 725px;
 max-width: 960px;
 margin-left: auto;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(15,26,155,1); */
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
}



.topimage {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 960px;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 175px;
 /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(0,102,204,1); */
 position: absolute;
 /* [disabled]border: thin solid rgba(255,0,0,1); */
}

.topimage img{
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 /* [disabled]margin-bottom: -9px; */
 display: block;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
}

.menu {
 background-color: rgba(15,26,155,1);
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 50px;
 max-width: 960px;
 position: relative;
 top: 175px;
}
.list {
 color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
 padding: 0px;
}

.list li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 width: auto;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(204,255,0,1);
 position: relative;
 padding: 0px;
}

.content {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: rgba(20,35,214,1);
 position: relative;
 top: 175px;
 padding-right: 0.5%;
 padding-left: 0.5%;
}

.leftcontent {
 background-color: rgba(210,238,252,1);
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 85%;
 top: 0px;
 position: relative;
 border-left-color: rgba(205,205,205,1);
 /* [disabled]margin-left: 0.3%; */
}

.rightcontent {
 background-color: rgba(51,177,236,1);
 float: right;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 15%;
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 /* [disabled]margin-right: 0.3%; */
}

.footer {
 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="topimage">

</div>
<div class="menu">
<ul class="list">
<li>Home</li>
<li>Products</li>
<li>Services</li>
<li>About Us</li>
<li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
<div class="leftcontent">
</div>
<div class="rightcontent">
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This is an old known issue, have you search before asking?

Answer (score 0):

If you have no new lines between the list elements then it works. So you could put all on one line (see snippet) or add `font-size: 0;` to the `<ul>`

```
ul {font-size:0;}
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}


html,body {
 margin: 0px;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 background-color: rgba(173,192,241,1);
    }

.wrapper {
 height: 725px;
 max-width: 960px;
 margin-left: auto;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(15,26,155,1); */
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
}



.topimage {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 960px;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 175px;
 /* [disabled]background-color: rgba(0,102,204,1); */
 position: absolute;
 /* [disabled]border: thin solid rgba(255,0,0,1); */
}

.topimage img{
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
 /* [disabled]margin-bottom: -9px; */
 display: block;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
}

.menu {
 background-color: rgba(15,26,155,1);
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 50px;
 max-width: 960px;
 position: relative;
 top: 175px;
}
.list {
 color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-color: rgba(255,0,0,1);
 padding: 0px;
}

.list li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 width: auto;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: rgba(204,255,0,1);
 position: relative;
 padding: 0px;
}

.content {
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: rgba(20,35,214,1);
 position: relative;
 top: 175px;
 padding-right: 0.5%;
 padding-left: 0.5%;
}

.leftcontent {
 background-color: rgba(210,238,252,1);
 float: left;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 85%;
 top: 0px;
 position: relative;
 border-left-color: rgba(205,205,205,1);
 /* [disabled]margin-left: 0.3%; */
}

.rightcontent {
 background-color: rgba(51,177,236,1);
 float: right;
 height: 100%;
 max-height: 500px;
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 15%;
 position: relative;
 top: 0px;
 /* [disabled]margin-right: 0.3%; */
}

.footer {
 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="topimage">

</div>
<div class="menu">
<ul class="list">
<li>Home</li><li>Products</li><li>Services</li><li>About Us</li><li>Contact</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
<div class="leftcontent">
</div>
<div class="rightcontent">
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: The single-line thing seems like a very hacky solution. And very un-scalable for larger amounts of list elements.

Comment: Agreed. That's why i suggested a better solution using `font-size:0;`.

Comment: Hello Ben. Thanks for your answer. Could you please tell me what changes you did to the above code? Am not able to identify :(

Comment: I put the `<li>` elements on one line so there is not a gap. Display inline-block basically makes the `<li>` act like words. And words have spaces between them. So the above way makes it like one long word (so no spaces). You can also use a 0 font-size on the `<ul>`, like i said above, to make those spaces basically invisible.

Comment: Or just not use `display: inline-block;` at all, as others have said. And just use `float:left;` instead. Up to you :)  hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove space created by `inline-block` element as with following trick.
Or you can use `float` instead of `inline-block`.

```
.list {
  letter-spacing: -4px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.list li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Or you can use `float`:

```
.list {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list li {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
.list li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(204,255,0,1);
    position: relative;
}
```

Replace with above css with your existing `.list li` class

Comment: Hello, i used float:left on li , and I was able to get rid of space. However, the moment I used float:left on li, the background color of the `.list` (which is red) disappeared. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this into your code,

```
.list{
font-size:0;
}
.list li{
font-size:20px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 10px;
}
```